# requirejs always triggers "onload" in IE, even if the file is not there

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, require

Following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.5/require.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            require(["nothere.js"], function()
            {
                alert("onload!");
            }, 
            function onerror(e)
            {
                alert("error!");
                console.log("error! - ", e);
            });  
        </script>

    </head>
</html>
```

Chrome and Firefox show **error** as expected, because the *nothere.js* file is not there and couldn't be loaded.

However, IE (in every version) shows the **onload**. Any ideas?

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/AJu2j/

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for now (of course not the best solution):

```
var myrequire = function(file, onload, onerror)
{
    require([file], function(module)
    {
        if (typeof module == "object")
            return onload(module);

        return onerror();
    }, 
    onerror); 
}
```